# Graphiql does not display incoming data for subscriptions

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphiql

I implemented a graphql server using *graphql-java* that offers subscriptions over websockets.

When I subscribe using the websocket CL-tool *wscat* everything works as intended.

Here is how the data looks that the server publishes (<):

```
$wscat -c "ws://localhost:9876/subscriptions"
> { "query" : "subscription{resourceSubscription(hasTypes : []){id}}" }
< {"type":"subscription_success"}   
< {"payload":{"data":{"resourceSubscription":{"id":"..."}}},"id":"1","type":"subscription_data"} (*1)
```

The JSON response format is copied from [this](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/how-to-use-subscriptions-in-graphiql-1d6ab8dbd74b/) tutorial. I have also tried to just send the "data" block without the "payload" wrapper.

For graphiql I use the *graphiql-spring-boot-starter v7.1.0* package. When I fire a subscription from graphiql, the display shows:

> "Your subscription data will appear here after server publication!"

*graphiql* sends the query to the websocket endpoint:

> {"type":"connection_init","payload":{}}

> {"id":"1","type":"start","payload":{"query":"subscription[...]","variables":null}}

A websocket is created on the server, and new data is actually published to the established websocket (like in *1), however, it is not displayed in *graphiql*, the incoming data is completely ignored and the prompt remains.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Is the JSON response not formatted correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The necessary response types is:
{"type": "data",...} instead of {"type" : "subscription_data",...}